# CodeIgniter form validation, cannot get validation error

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm attempting to use CodeIgniters form validation library, and despite my validation rules appearing to work, whenever I call validation_errors(), I get an empty string.

Here's a code snippet.

```
$base_rules = 'required|trim';

$this->_validation_rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'name',
            'rules' => $base_rules . '|alpha_numeric|min_length[5]|max_length[30]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'price',
            'label' => 'Price',
            'rules' => $base_rules . '|decimal'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'duration',
            'label' => 'Duration',
            'rules' => $base_rules . '|integer'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'booking',
            'label' => 'Booking',
            'rules' => $base_rules . '|integer'
        )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->_validation_rules);

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        // do stuff
    }else{
        // prints an empty string
         var_dump(validation_errors());
         exit;
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is the case, and how I can get my errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put validation_errors() on top of your form, and change your code to

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        // do stuff
    }else{
       $this->load->view('myform'); //display your form again
    }
```

validation_errors() will only by poplated in a view.

Comment: Great thanks, one question though - does this mean there is no way of storing the validation errors in flashdata or some other storage so I can redirect somewhere else? Cheers

Comment: @John what if we're sending an AJAX request? of-course, then we need to get the errors in Controller rather than View. So, is there any solution to get errors in Controller? `validation_errors()` is not working in Controller.

Answer (score 1):

put this code top of form in view file

```
echo validation_errors('<div>', '</div>');
```

then change else to this

```
else{
    $this->load->view('myform'); //display your form again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete John answer, if you did a form post you can put under your inputs :

```
<?php echo form_error('input-name'); ?>
```

But if you're making an ajax request(wich is not your case now but in the future if you need)
you can use the validation_errors().

Here an exemple :

```
    //Important to turn that off if it's on
    $this->output->enable_profiler(false); 

    $this->output->set_status_header('500');
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');

    echo json_encode(array(
        'error_msg' => validation_errors(),
    ));
```

And then on your client-side you can use the response like that :

```
error:function(data) {
    $("your-error-input-selector").html('').append(data.responseJSON.msg);
}
```

Hope i helped even if i'm 1 year late.

P.S Sorry for my broken english.

Comment: Did you add your form validation ? Did you run your validation ? can i take a look at your code ? I'll be more than happy to help you !